# sendRawTransaction fail with "Invalid Sender" on Ropsten but works on Local Node

Tags: web3js, dapps, ropsten

I have a simple contract deployed successfully to the Ropsten test network using Remix (Verified using https://ropsten.etherscan.io)

Same contract has been deployed to my local private node and I could successfully interact with it using my sample DAPP.

When I try to send a transaction using “*sendRawTransaction*”, it fails with “*invalid sender*” error message.

I have used the relevant addresses for each network and have specify the correct chainID for each network (chainId 3 for Ropsten).

Following are the functions I have used.

```
async function execInRopstenEx(){
var Web3 = require('web3');
var util = require('ethereumjs-util');
var lightwallet = require('eth-lightwallet');
var txutils = lightwallet.txutils;

var web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/<MY_TOKEN>'));
    //new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8080'));

var address = '<FROM_ADDRESS>';
var address2 = 'CONTRACT_ADDRESS';
var key = '<MY_PRIVATE_KEY>';
var currentChainId = 3;

var amount = web3.toWei(0.2, "ether");
var balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(address);

var value = web3.fromWei(balance, 'ether');

console.log(value);

var rawTx = {
    //nonce: web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)),
    nonce: web3.toHex(2),        
    gasPrice: "0x9184e72a000",
    chainId:currentChainId,
    gasLimit: web3.toHex(210000),
    to: address2,
    from:address,
    input:0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
}

console.log("rawTxn ",rawTx);
sendRaw(rawTx,key);}

async function sendRaw(rawTx, key) {
var tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var privateKey = new Buffer(key, 'hex');
var transaction = new tx(rawTx);
transaction.sign(privateKey);
var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');
await web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(
    '0x' + serializedTx, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: This is a great question. Does someone know the answer?